# WordPress. can't see post editor tools

Tags: wordpress

Trying to write first post in WordPress site.
But post editor tab extremely empty:
[image]

How can I editor tools tab like this:
[image]

including language switching.
P.s. multi language plugin installed.

Comment: this is because wordpress use new editor called Block editor. 
to role back to previous editor you have to install a plugin called `classic editor`

Comment: Thank you! It helped. Can you make an answer for question so I can mark it?)

Answer (score 0):

Install WordPress [classic editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/) to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

the best solution for your question is that install a plugin called `Classic Editor` for download that you can search in plugin installation page with its name or click Download button [In This Page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/)